# Question involving Taylor's theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, taylor-expansion

Let $f \colon \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a $C^2$ function. Prove:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n^2\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx-n\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(\frac{2k-1}{2n}\right)\right)=\frac{f'(1)-f'(0)}{24}$$

Our professor gave us this question and said that it involves the use of Taylor's theorem. However I don't even know how to start this. Kindly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can write
$$
n^2 \int_0^1 {f(x)dx}  = n^2 \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\int_{(k - 1)/n}^{k/n} {f(x)dx} }  = n\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\int_{k - 1}^k {f\left( {\frac{t}{n}} \right)dt} } .
$$
For $k - 1 < t < k$, the Taylor formula tells us that
\begin{align*}
f\left( {\frac{t}{n}} \right) = f\left( {\frac{{2t}}{{2n}}} \right) = f\left( {\frac{{2k - 1}}{{2n}}} \right) & + f'\!\left( {\frac{{2k - 1}}{{2n}}} \right)\left( {\frac{{2t - 2k + 1}}{{2n}}} \right) \\ & + \frac{1}{2}f''\!\left( {\frac{{k - \delta _k (t)}}{n}} \right)\left( {\frac{{2t - 2k + 1}}{{2n}}} \right)^2 
\end{align*}
with some $0 < \delta _k (t) < 1$. Thus, by the mean value theorem for integration
$$
n^2 \int_0^1 {f(x)dx}  = n\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {f\left( {\frac{{2k - 1}}{{2n}}} \right)}  + \frac{1}{{24n}}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {f''\!\left( {\frac{{k - \zeta _k }}{n}} \right)} 
$$
with some $0<\zeta_k<1$. Finally,
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{1}{{24n}}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {f''\!\left( {\frac{{k - \zeta _k }}{n}} \right)}  = \frac{1}{{24}}\int_0^1 {f''(x)dx}  = \frac{{f'(1) - f'(0)}}{{24}}.
$$
I leave you the details.

Comment: could you elaborate on how you went from the second step to the third step?

Comment: You substitute the Taylor expression into the form at the end of the first step. When you perform the integration from $k-1$ to $k$, the part involving the first derivative disappears. To integrate the term involving the second derivative, you "factor out" the second derivative from the integral using the mean value theorem for integrals and integrate only the square of $(2t-2k+1)/(2n)$.