# Finding the limit of this functional expression

Tags: calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be such that $f(x)$ is twice differentiable and $f^{\prime \prime}(x)$ is continuous. Show the following limit .

> $$
> \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(n^{2} \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \mathrm{d} x-n \sum_{k=1}^{n} f\left(\frac{2 k-1}{2 n}\right)\right)=\frac{f^{\prime}(1)-f^{\prime}(0)}{24}
> $$.                                   My approach was to suppose write f(x) as integral of f'(x) dx and simplifying but it was not helpful at all .

Comment: If you're allowed the mean value theorem for integration (not really difficult to prove in any case) then [Question involving Taylor's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4020315/question-involving-taylors-theorem) should do your job.

Comment: Thank you yes we are allowed

Comment: Good to know, thanks for the feedback.